# How can I refactor my Controller Action to not be so complex?

Tags: c#, mvc

I'm building a website that is used to search our system.  The users can search on a lot of critera at once.  As I try to do this though, I can't figure out how to simplify this horrible action.

```
public ActionResult Search(SearchViewModel model)
{
    Expression<Func<Parcel, bool>> filterexpression = PredicateBuilder.True<Parcel>();

    this.TryUpdateModel(model);

    IQueryable<Parcel> query = service.GetAllParcels().AsQueryable();

    if (model == null)
    {
        model = new SearchViewModel();
    }

    // TODO: add conditions to only include expressions that have values
    if (model.ParcelSearch.Strap != null)
    {
        filterexpression = filterexpression.And(service.StrapStartsWith(model.ParcelSearch.Strap.AsStrap()));
    }

    if (model.ParcelSearch.OwnerKeywords != null)
    {
        filterexpression = filterexpression.And(service.ContainsInOwnerName(model.ParcelSearch.OwnerKeywords));
    }

    if (model.ParcelSearch.AddressKeywords != null)
    {
        filterexpression = filterexpression.And(service.ContainsInAddress(model.ParcelSearch.AddressKeywords));
    }

    if (model.ParcelSearch.ZipCode != null)
    {
        filterexpression = filterexpression.And(service.LocatedWithinZipCode(model.ParcelSearch.ZipCode));
    }

    if (model.ParcelSearch.Subdivision != null)
    {
        filterexpression = filterexpression.And(service.IsInSubdivision(model.ParcelSearch.Subdivision));
    }

    // TODO: add boolean conditions. no need to check these for nulls ATM.
    filterexpression =
        filterexpression.Expand()
            .And(service.HasDock(model.PropertyFeatureSearch.Dock))
            .And(service.HasPool(model.PropertyFeatureSearch.Pool))
            .And(service.HasSeaWall(model.PropertyFeatureSearch.SeaWall))
            .And(service.HasTennisCourt(model.PropertyFeatureSearch.Tennis))
            .And(service.IsVacant(model.PropertyFeatureSearch.VacantLand))
            .And(service.IsNew(model.PropertyFeatureSearch.StatusNew))
            .Expand();

    if (model.SalesSearch.SalesFrom != null && model.SalesSearch.SalesTo != null)
    {
        filterexpression =
            filterexpression.And(
                service.SalesInRange(model.SalesSearch.SalesFrom.Value, model.SalesSearch.SalesTo.Value));
    }

    if (model.SalesSearch.SaleAmountFrom != null && model.SalesSearch.SaleAmountTo != null)
    {
        filterexpression =
            filterexpression.And(
                service.SalesAmountInRange(model.SalesSearch.SaleAmountFrom, model.SalesSearch.SaleAmountTo))
                .Expand();
    }

    if (model.SalesSearch.InstrumentNumber != null)
    {
        filterexpression = 
            filterexpression.And(service.SalesWithInstrumentNumber(model.SalesSearch.InstrumentNumber));
    }

    if (model.SalesSearch.GrantorSeller != null)
    {
        filterexpression = 
            filterexpression.And(service.GrantorSellerContains(model.SalesSearch.GrantorSeller));
    }

    if (model.ParcelSearch.UseCode != null)
    {
        filterexpression = 
            filterexpression.And(service.UseCodeEquals(model.ParcelSearch.UseCode));
    }

    // TODO:CREATE SEARCHING HERE
    var timer = new Stopwatch();

    timer.Start();
    query = query.Where(filterexpression.Expand());

    this.TempData["filter"] = filterexpression;

    this.ViewData["count"] = query.Count();

    IQueryable<Parcel> output;

    if (model.SortOption == "strap")
    {
        output = query.OrderBy(x => x.STRAP).Take(500);
    }
    else if (model.SortOption == "PropertyUse")
    {
        output = query.OrderBy(x => x.PROPERTY_USE).Take(500);
    }
    else
    {
        output = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.LastUpdated).Take(500);
    }

    int page = model.Page ?? 1;
    if ((int)this.ViewData["count"] < (page + 1) * 10)
    {
        page = 1;
    }

    model.SearchResults = output.AsPagination(page, 10);
    timer.Stop();
    Debug.Assert(timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.CompareTo(10) < 0, "Query exceeded a reasonable amount of time");
    Debug.Print(timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    ViewData["executionTime"] = timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    if (model.UseAdvancedSearch)
    {
        return this.View("AdvancedSearch", model);
    }
    return this.View(model);
}
```

## Update - What a difference so far.

```
 public ActionResult Search(SearchViewModel model)
        {

            if (model == null)
            {
                model = new SearchViewModel();
            }

            this.TryUpdateModel(model);

            if (this.TryValidateModel(model))
            {
                //model validated. Go ahead and apply filter.
                this.ApplyCriteriaFilter(model);
                //figure out the count

            }
            else
            {
                //model didn't validate so do something.
            }

            IQueryable<Parcel> query = service.GetAllParcels().AsQueryable().Where(this.filterexpression);

            // TODO:CREATE SEARCHING HERE
            var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            this.ViewData["count"] = query.Count();

            query = this.Sort(query, model.SortOption);

            //refactor this guy
            int page = model.Page ?? 1;
            if ((int)this.ViewData["count"] < (page + 1) * 10)
            {
                page = 1;
            }

            model.SearchResults = query.AsPagination(page, 10);
            timer.Stop();
            Debug.Assert(timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds < 10, "Query exceeded a reasonable amount of time");
            Debug.Print(timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            this.ViewData["executionTime"] = timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            if (model.UseAdvancedSearch)
            {
                return this.View("AdvancedSearch", model);
            }

            return this.View(model);
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

I imagine you want to get rid of repetitive `if/And` blocks. To do that, you may start by generalizing the following pattern (note: I'm using `object` since you haven't specified the precise types you use; in your case, `object` will be replaced by something more specific).

```
var includeExpression = new Action<Func<bool>, object>(
    (predicate, obj) =>
    {
        if (predicate)
        {
            filterexpression = filterexpression.And(obj);
        }
    });
```

This makes it possible to rewrite all those repetitive blocks in a more compact way:

```
includeExpression(
    model.ParcelSearch.Strap != null,
    service.StrapStartsWith(model.ParcelSearch.Strap.AsStrap()));
```

You can push it a bit more for the first five blocks, by creating an additional function, based on the first one:

```
var includeIfNotNull = new Action<object, Func<Service, ParcelSearch, object>>(
    (eval, transform) =>
    {
        includeExpression(eval != null, transform(service, model.ParcelSearch)));
    });
```

Now, you can simply write:

```
includeIfNotNull(model.ParcelSearch.Strap, (s, p) => s.StrapStartsWith(p.Strap.AsStrap()));
```

given that this last optimization would be available only for the first five blocks.

An additional rewrite would be to make an `IEnumerable` containing the predicates and the objects, and call `includeIfNotNull` inside the first `foreach` for the first five entries, then `includeExpression` inside the second `foreach` for the last five ones. However, I'm not convinced that it would improve readability.

A few other suggestions:

- Putting the first five and the last five blocks in separate methods would make things clearer, IMO. This also applies to the block:

  ```
  filterexpression =
      filterexpression.Expand()
                      .And(service.HasDock(model.PropertyFeatureSearch.Dock))
                      .And(service.HasPool(model.PropertyFeatureSearch.Pool))
                      .And(service.HasSeaWall(model.PropertyFeatureSearch.SeaWall))
                      .And(service.HasTennisCourt(model.PropertyFeatureSearch.Tennis))
                      .And(service.IsVacant(model.PropertyFeatureSearch.VacantLand))
                      .And(service.IsNew(model.PropertyFeatureSearch.StatusNew))
                      .Expand();
  ```
- The code:

  ```
  var timer = new Stopwatch();
  timer.Start();
  ```

  should be:

  ```
  var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
  ```
- What about extracting:

  ```
  IQueryable<Parcel> output;

  if (model.SortOption == "strap")
  {
      output = query.OrderBy(x => x.STRAP).Take(500);
  }
  else if (model.SortOption == "PropertyUse")
  {
      output = query.OrderBy(x => x.PROPERTY_USE).Take(500);
  }
  else
  {
      output = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.LastUpdated).Take(500);
  }
  ```

  into a separate method which returns `IQueryable<Parcel>`?
- `timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.CompareTo(10) < 0` is totally weird and error prone. You should have used `timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds > 10` instead.
- Put the measurement of time into a method which takes an `Action` as a parameter, like:

  ```
  private static long MeasureTime(Action action)
  {
      var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
      action();
      return timer.Milliseconds();
  }
  ```

  so instead of having:

  ```
  var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
  Run();
  Some();
  Code();
  timer.Stop();
  LogElapsedTime(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
  ```

  you can simply write:

  ```
  var elapsedMilliseconds = MyClass.MeasureTime(
      () =>
      {
          Run();
          Some();
          Code();
      });

  LogElapsedTime(elapsedMilliseconds);
  ```

  or instead of:

  ```
  var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
  RunSomeCode();
  timer.Stop();
  LogElapsedTime(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
  ```

  you can have:

  ```
  var elapsedMilliseconds = MyClass.MeasureTime(RunSomeCode);
  LogElapsedTime(elapsedMilliseconds);
  ```

Comment: This is turning out great so far.  Should maybe these two Actions you define be moved out to my service layer?

Comment: Also can you elaborate on `Put the measurement of time into a method which takes an Action as a parameter` Merci Beaucoup

Comment: @MVCylon: done. See the last edit.